# How to persist dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration?

Tags: keyboard

I have an ASUS K45A and am using UBUNTU 14.10.

To type <kbd>/</kbd> and other characters, I have to use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

Every time I boot my machine I have to `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` to set the correct configuration.

Can I permanently change this? I've already tried `sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard`, but it did not work.

Comment: You are using a non US keybord!
To not use [Alt Gr] everytime, install a standard US-keyboard, and when needed shift keyboard, from your local to the US-keyboard. When finished change back to your local.

Comment: How are you running Ubuntu? Are you using a live CD/DVD/USB medium or did you install it?

Comment: Eduardo: You can also install US International...  That way you can type ç, ñ, ... as well.  Get rid of all other keyboard (and off course: install a QWERTY US hardware keyboard...)  Please report back on this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved with this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

after that the configuration never reset after shutdown of my machine.